# plot new values for best fit nonlinear curve

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions, best-fit-curve

I have created the best fit for a non linear function. It seems to be working correctly:

```
#define a function
fncTtr <- function(n,d) (d/n)*((sqrt(1+2*(n/d))-1))

#fit
dFit <- nls(dData$ttr~fncTtr(dData$n,d),data=dData,start=list(d=25),trace=T)
summary(dFit)

plot(dData$ttr~dData$n,main="Fitted d value",pch=19,)
xl <- seq(min(dData$n),max(dData$n), (max(dData$n) - min(dData$n))/1000)

lines(xl,predict(dFit,newdata=xl,col=blue)
```

The plot for my observations are coming out correctly. I am having problems to display the best fit curve on my plot. I create the xl independent variable with 1000 values and I want to define the new values using the best fit. When I call the "lines" procedure, I get the error message:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
>   If I try to execute only the predict function:

```
a <-predict(dFit,newdata=xl)
str(a)
```

I can see that xl has 1000 components but "a" has only 16 components. Shouldn't I have the same number of values in a?

data used:

```
  n    ttr      d
1  35 0.6951 27.739
2  36 0.6925 28.072
3  37 0.6905 28.507
4  38 0.6887 28.946
5  39 0.6790 28.003
6  40 0.6703 27.247
7  41 0.6566 25.735
8  42 0.6605 26.981
9  43 0.6567 27.016
10 44 0.6466 26.026
11 45 0.6531 27.667
12 46 0.6461 27.128
13 47 0.6336 25.751
14 48 0.6225 24.636
15 49 0.6214 24.992
16 50 0.6248 26.011
```

Comment: Would it be possible to include your data or a sample of your data so that we can try your code and see where the problem comes from?

Comment: I have attached the data

Comment: I should add that I am new at R. I have made a number of estimations of the "d-values" (in the data).The purpose of the program is to optimize the "d value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the solution, however I'm not sure I would be able to explain it.
When calling `predict.nls`, what you're inputting to argument `newdata` has to be named according to the variable with which you're predicting (here `n`) and the name has to match that given in the original call to `nls`.

```
#Here I replaced dData$n with n
dFit <- nls(ttr~fncTtr(n,d),data=dData,start=list(d=25),trace=T)

plot(dData$ttr~dData$n,main="Fitted d value",pch=19,)
xl <- seq(min(dData$n),max(dData$n), (max(dData$n) - min(dData$n))/1000)

a <- predict(dFit,newdata=list(n=xl))
length(a)==length(xl)
[1] TRUE

lines(xl,a,col="blue")
```

[image]